# Function With Multiple Values JavaScript+JSP+Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a project in Java with JSP+JavaScript+Servlets, with a function in JavaScript to find some record in my database. When this record is found, my function returns some value, and when it's not, my function returns a message. Now I need another function to return several fields from my database, and I don't know who. I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and JSP.
EDIT: I did some changes

This is part from my JSP code:

```
 <%
     HashMap row = new HashMap();
 %>
 <tr>
    <td>
     <input type='text' id="noeco" name="noeco" size=5 maxlength=5 onkeyup="find_noeco_s(noeco,row);">
     <span name="exists" id="exists" readonly="readonly" style="width: 200px" value='{row.get("exists")}'></span></input>                            
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <input type='text' id="matric" name="matric" readonly="readonly"  value="{row.get('matri')}"></input>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <input type='text' id="marca" name="marca" readonly="readonly" value="{row.get('marca')}"></input>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

This is my JavaScript function "find_noeco_s":

```
function find_noeco_s(noeco,row){
   objsal = row;
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
       ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   else
       ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   ajax.onreadystatechange = funcionCallback;

   ajax.open("GET", "/processEco.jsp?noeco="+noeco.value, true);
   ajax.send("");
```

}

And this is my JSP processEco:

```
String noeco = request.getParameter("noeco");
String exists="";
String matri= "";
HashMap row = new HashMap();
try{
   PreparedStatement ps = PV.prepareStatement("select * from vehicles where econom=?");
   ps.setString(1, noeco);
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
   if(rs.next()){
        exists= rs.getString("dstipveh");
        matri = rs.getString("matr");
        marca= rs.getString("marca");
        row.put("exists", exists);
        row.put("matr", matr);
        row.put("marca", marca);
   }else{
        exists= "DOES NOT EXISTS";
        row.put("exists", exists);
   }
%>
<%=row%>
<% 
}finally{}      
%>
```

But I get just one value (exists). Like I said, I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and JSP. So, how can I return several values and display this values in my JSP like I do with just one value?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question requirement club all the fields into an object , and return that object from your method call.

e.g :

```
  Class MyReturnTypeData {
  private String exists;
  private String matr;
  private String marca;
  ....

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a hashmap.

```
HashMap row = new HashMap();
if(rs.next()){
exists= rs.getString("dstipveh");
matri = rs.getString("matr");
marca= rs.getString("marca");
row.put("exists", exists);
row.put("matr", matr);
row.put("marca", marca);
}
else
{
exists= "DOES NOT EXISTS";
row.put("exists", exists);
}
return row;
```

then to retrieve the values

```
<%
if (row.get("exists").equals("DOES NOT EXISTS"))
{
out.println(row.get("exists"));
}
else
{
out.println(row.get("exists"));
out.println(row.get("matr"));
out.println(row.get("marca"));
}
%>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did some changes like you suggested me, but "row" is always empty, I can't display the value in my JSP. Like I said, I'm not very familiar with JSP and JS. What I'm missing?

Comment: is the database query happening in a seperate method from where you are trying to display the values, or are they happening in the same method?

Comment: In a different method... My first code is my JSP who's displaying the values (form JSP). My second code is mi JS (where find_noeco_s function is), which is called in my JSP, and my third code is another JSP who's called from my JS (processEco.jsp)